# Split string into numbers with Python

Tags: python

For example, I want to get List `[1.0, 2.0, -3.0]` from string `"1+2-3.0"` but I don't have any ideas how to do this.

What's your thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to specify the requirements better first. Why do you want `-3.0` instead of `3.0`?

Comment: What happened to the `+` between `1+2`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Note sure I think he needs `1, 2` because `+2` == `2`. So I think @Abhijit answer is perfect

Comment: The point being, the question is poorly expressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex you can do this quite easily. The result which would be a list of strings should be finally converted to float to match your result.

**Implementation**

```
import re
s = "1+2-3.0"
map(float, re.findall("([+-]?[\d\.]+)", s))
```

*If You are using Python 3.X, remember to convert your map to list as it returns a map object. Otherwise, use a List Comprehension*

```
[float(e) for e in re.split("[+-]", s)]
```

**Regex Explanation**

*Find all the numbers (digits and period) that is prefixed with a sign*

**Output**

```
[1.0, 2.0, -3.0]
```

Comment: `map(float, re.split("[+-]", s))` is not working as expected.

Comment: @PriyankPatel: May be you are using Python 3.X

Comment: Nope . `2.7.3` . o/p is `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` .

Comment: and what's the decision for 3.X?

Comment: `re.split` version ignores signs.

Comment: @user2733016, Use list comprehension or `list(map(...))`.

Comment: @PriyankPatel: Yes, you are correct. I just overlooked that `re.split` ignores sign